# react select show and hide menuList

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

I am trying to use react-select. I have certain condition (boolean), when the param is `true`, some property/attribute of the react-select would change base on the logic. One if them is `menuList`. My objective, if the param is `true`, I want the `menuList` displayed and searchable, but when `false`, I want the `menuList` hidden but still available (not disabled, thats why I use `onChange` and `onInputChange` prop). Here is what I've set so far:

```
const isExist = true;
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '50%', margin: 20 }}>
        <Select
          id="asd"
          value={selectedOption}
          onChange={isExist ? this.handleChange : null}
          onInputChange={isExist ? null : e => this.tests(e) }
          options={options}
          isClearable={true}
          styles={style}
          placeholder="Please type"
          noOptionsMessage={() => isExist ? 'Zero Result' : null}
          components={{ MenuList: () => isExist ? 'display the menu but how?' : null }}
        />
      </div>
    );
```

any help would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the behaviour you describe you could use a controlled `menuIsOpen` props like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isExist: false,
      menuIsOpen: false,
      selectedOption: null
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: e
    });
  };

  onInputChange = (options, { action }) => {
    if (this.state.isExist) {
      if (action === "menu-close") {
        this.setState({ menuIsOpen: false });
      }
    } else {
      if (action === "input-change") {
        // do whatever you want with the entered value
      }
    }
  };

  onFocus = e => {
    if (this.state.isExist) this.setState({ menuIsOpen: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: "50%", margin: 20 }}>
        <Select
          id="asd"
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onFocus={this.onFocus}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          options={options}
          isClearable={true}
          placeholder="Please type"
          noOptionsMessage={() => (this.state.isExist ? "Zero Result" : null)}
          menuIsOpen={this.state.menuIsOpen}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n40zn7nl9j).

Comment: but if I use isDisabled, I couldnt type anything into the input. I need to keep the input available, just the menuList that will be hidden if the params is false. Thats why I use onChange when the param is true and use onInputChange when the param is false to get the value that typed/choosen by the user. But, I dont know how to show the menuList if the param is true

Comment: So the sum up the user will be able to type in the input but the menu won't open and no option can be enter right ?

Comment: yes, no option (from the list) selected. so, the use case is, i have a checkbox, if the checkbox checked, then the select has menuList that user can search and select (i got the value using onChange). But, if the checkbox is not checked, user can type in the input, but no menuList display, and I got the value of user input by onInputChange event

Comment: @Akza I have updated my code to provide a different approach

Comment: Thank you soooo much! u save my night! So I can sleep in peace now :)